# Array input from the user

Tags: visual-studio

How to make an array that is input from the user?
I have tried to make a Ceasuar cipher program and wanted to make an array that contain user plaintext.

Comment: maybe you can add more tags about editors and IDE's and all the languages that SO users use

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.